# Pandas - Replace None Value

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I get the data from database in my Python script and then storing the values in variables as follows:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query('EXEC script, dbcn)
durationCurrent = df.loc[df['Indicator'] == 'Duration Current']['IndicatorValue'].values[0]
```

but sometimes the value returned is `None`.

How to adjust the script to replace the `None` values for a custom string, e.g. `"Unknown"`?

Comment: `fillna('Unknown')`

Comment: Hm, I tried that and the None values are still in the dataframe. But hopefully this will point me further in the pandas docs. Thanks anyway.

Comment: try `df.replace(None, 'Unknown')` or `df.replace('None', 'Unknown')`. The way you'll do this depends on the data type of your columns and values

Comment: if you want to update/modify the original data frame, include `inplace=True` option in `fillna`.

Comment: df.fillna('Unknown', inplace=True) did the trick. Thanks once again. These "minor features" always take the most time.